# Creating SwiftReachability Class in Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am novice at creating independent classes for user. I have seen many `Reachability` library for Swift, but I need to create my own class for that. Here is my code:

```
class SwiftReachability: NSObject {

let REACHABILITY_NOTIFIER_KEY = "reachability_notifier_key"
var backgroundQueue: NSOperationQueue?
var isCancelled: Bool = false

//MARK: - Checking Internet Connecion
func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool{

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {

        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)

    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags)

    #if DEBUG
        print("Reachability flags = \(flags.rawValue) uint = \(UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable))")
    #endif

    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
}

func startNotifier(){

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SwiftReachability.networkConnectionObserver), name: REACHABILITY_NOTIFIER_KEY, object: nil)
    callingBackgroungThread()
}

func stopNotifier(){

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: REACHABILITY_NOTIFIER_KEY, object: nil)
    backgroundQueue?.cancelAllOperations()
    isCancelled = true
}

func callingBackgroungThread(){

    backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    let operation = NSBlockOperation {

        if self.isConnectedToNetwork(){

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.REACHABILITY_NOTIFIER_KEY, object:nil)
        }
    }

    operation.completionBlock = {

        if !self.isCancelled{

            self.callingBackgroungThread()
        }
    }

    delay(5.0, closure: {

        if !self.isCancelled{

            self.backgroundQueue?.addOperation(operation)
        }
    })
}

func networkConnectionObserver(){

    print("Observer")
    showAlert("Network Identified")
}

//MARK: Dispatch Asyn Queue After
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func showAlert(message: String){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bing", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

        self.stopNotifier()
    })

    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
}
```

Can anyone review it to make it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Improvements of your code

Let's start with your `isConnectedToNetwork()` method.

> ```
> var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
> ```

As of Swift 1.2(?), all imported C structs have a default initializer which sets all
members to zero:

```
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
```

> ```
> let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
>     SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
>  }
> ```

Here `defaultRouteReachability` is an *optional* which is later force-unwrapped.
Better check with `guard` and optional binding if the call succeeded:

```
guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
}) else {
    NSLog("Could not create reachability reference")
    return false
}
```

> ```
> var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
> ```

This can be shorted to

```
var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
// or
var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
```

> ```
> let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
> let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
> ```

`SCNetworkReachabilityFlags` is an `OptionSetType` and that has a set-like interface,
there is no need for `rawValue` and `UInt32` conversion:

```
let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
```

Finally, there is no reason to make this an *instance* method because it does not use
any state, you could make it a *type* method instead. Then it would look like this:

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool{

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        NSLog("Could not create reachability reference")
        return false
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags)

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
    return isReachable && !needsConnection
}
```

---

Your *notification mechanism* is far too complicated in my opinion. Instead of
scheduling an `NSOperation` which reschedules itself with `dispatch_after`, you could
simply create a repeating `NSTimer`. Also you should check if the
`startNotifier`/`stopNotifier` calls are properly balanced.

Even better, you can register a *notification callback* which is automatically called
when the reachability status changes. I'll come back to that later.

---

The `SwiftReachability` class should not do any UI-related stuff like displaying
alerts. Use `NSNotification` or callback methods to make the class reusable.

---

#### A different design

Let's have a look at the ["Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html)
document from Apple:

> **Connect Without Preflight**
>
> The Reachability APIs (see SCNetworkReachability Reference) are intended for diagnostic
>   purposes after identifying a connectivity issue. Many apps incorrectly use these APIs
>   to proactively check for an Internet connection by calling the SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress
>   method and passing it an IPv4 address of 0.0.0.0, which indicates that there is a
>   router on the network. However, the presence of a router doesn’t guarantee that an
>   Internet connection exists. In general, avoid preflighting network reachability.
>   Just try to make a connection and gracefully handle failures. If you must check for
>   network availability, avoid calling the SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress method.
>   Call the SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName method and pass it a hostname instead.

Your method can only test for general Internet connectivity (reachability of 0.0.0.0),
but not for reachability of a given host (as recommended by Apple).

To add this feature, it makes sense to make the `SCNetworkReachability` reference
a (private) instance variable, and provide multiple `init` methods:

```
class SwiftReachability {

    private let reachability: SCNetworkReachability

    init?() {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        guard let reachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.reachability = reachability
    }

    init?(hostname : String) {
        guard let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, hostname) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.reachability = reachability
    }
}
```

More init methods (e.g. for `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddressPair`) can be added
if necessary. The initializers are *failable*.

Checking the connection status consists of two parts:

- retrieve the `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags`,
- evaluate the `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags`.

For reasons that become more apparent later, I suggest to implement these as separate
methods. Retrieving the flags is done as above, only as an instance method:

```
class SwiftReachability {
    // ...

    func flags() -> SCNetworkReachabilityFlags {
        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags)
        return flags
    }
}
```

Computing the (boolean) connection status from the flags can be done as an extension
method of `SCNetworkReachabilityFlags`:

```
extension SCNetworkReachabilityFlags {
    func connected() -> Bool {
        let isReachable = self.contains(.Reachable)
        let needsConnection = self.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
        return isReachable && !needsConnection
    }
}
```

The reachability status can now be determined like this:

```
if let reachability = SwiftReachability(hostname: "google.com") {
    let connected = reachability.flags().connected()
    print(connected)
} else {
    print("Could not determine reachability status")
}
```

---

#### Change notifications

Instead of polling the connection status in regular intervals, you can register
a callback function which is called automatically if the status changes.

```
class SwiftReachability {
    // ...

    private var notifierActive = false
    var callback : ((SwiftReachability, SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Void)?

    func startNotifier() {
        if notifierActive { return }

        var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil,
                                                   retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
        context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, info) in
            let mySelf = Unmanaged<SwiftReachability>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(info)).takeUnretainedValue()
            mySelf.callback?(mySelf, flags)
        }, &context)

        SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachability, dispatch_get_main_queue())
        notifierActive = true
    }

    func stopNotifier() {
        if !notifierActive { return }

        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, nil, nil)
        SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachability, nil)
        notifierActive = false
    }

    deinit {
        stopNotifier()
    }
}
```

This is a bit tricky because the callback  is a pure C function. In Swift, this must
be a global function or a closure which does not capture any context. It is therefore
not possible to use `self` in the callback closure. Instead, the `self` instance
pointer must be to a `Void` pointer, passed to the callback, and converted back to
an instance pointer (`mySelf`), compare
[How to cast self to UnsafeMutablePointer type in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294620/how-to-cast-self-to-unsafemutablepointervoid-type-in-swift).

Here is a simple example how this could be used in view controller for regular
updates of the connection status:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var reachability : SwiftReachability?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        reachability = SwiftReachability()
        if let reach = reachability {
            reach.callback = { (_, flags) in
                let connected = flags.connected()
                print("Connected:", connected)
                // Update display, show alert, whatever ....
            }
            reach.startNotifier()
        } else {
            print("Could not determine connection status")
            // Update display, show alert, whatever ....
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the view controller must hold a reference to the reachability object.
The connection flags are passed to the callback, so now we can use the
`connected()` extension method which we defined above.

Of course, one could also use the `NSNotificationCenter` to inform clients of
changes in the connection status instead of a callback method.

*Remark:* There is an excellent implementation of Reachability in Swift: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift.
Similarities between that code and the code suggested here are not intentional but could not be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented and made some changes according to the requirement :)